# Content type biasing in Apache solr module for single content type

Tags: 7, search

I am working on displaying the search result using solr search and apache solr module in D7.

I have few content types let's say **Article, Blog, Video, News, Story, Page** etc.

I have given weight to each content type from **Type Bias** section of apache solr.

But, now I want to display the news as "*latest news first*" if it comes in the result. I tried it by using **Result biasing** section "*More recently created*" and have given the weight there. But it is affecting the result for all the content types, whereas I just want to display it for "**News**" content types. I tried to search a lot but didn't find an appropriate answer.

How can I do this?